# Why the declaration with equal operator is Error when I declare copy initializer is deleted

Tags: c++, c++11

The `class A` is declare as follow:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A() {
        cout<<"A()"<<'\n';
    }
    A(int i) {
        cout<<"A(int i)"<<'\n';
    }
    A(const A& a_) {
        cout<<"A(const A& a_)"<<'\n';
    }
};
```

When I initialize '**A**' by an integer with equal operator:

```cpp
int main() {
    A a = 123;
    return 0
}
```

Then it only output: `A(int i)` so I guess it only invoke `A::A(int i)` and the copy constructor is never used in this situation.

But when I declare `A::A(const A& a_) = delete`, the codes as follow:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A() {
        cout<<"A()"<<'\n';
    }
    A(int i) {
        cout<<"A(int i)"<<'\n';
    }
    A(const A& a_) = delete;
};
int main() {
    A a = 123;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler issues an error:

```
Copying variable of type 'A' invokes deleted constructor.
```

So my question is: **Why the copy constructor can't be deleted even it's not invoked in this situation?**

Comment: The copy-constructor is elided in the first case, which is why you only see a call to `A(int)` but even if it is elided, it must be available (until C++17) which is why deleting it makes your code ill-formed. The two duplicate links explain this in more depth.

Comment: Get it, thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean that if compiler don't optimize the code, the executable file compiled from the code will invoke **A(int)** to create a temporary variable and then invoke copy constructor to initialize **'a'** by the temporary variable just created?

Comment: Yes, until C++17. If you are using g++ or clang, you can pass the option `-fno-elide-constructors` to see this: https://godbolt.org/z/3IhPBm If you look at the generated assembly with `-fno-elide-constructors`, you'll notice a call to `A(int)` and a call to `A(const& A)`. Without the option, you get a single call to `A(int)` because the copy-constructor is elided. If you set `-std=c++17`, you will see only one call even with `-fno-elide-constructors` because copy-elision is guaranteed in such case since C++17.

Comment: Ok, I get it, you are very nice, thank you!